# Is it possible to make a high availability PostgreSQL database cluster by open source softwares?

Tags: postgresql, high-availability, pgbouncer, barman, repmgr

If use these tools can make a great modern database cluster with full features:

- pgbouncer (with HAProxy for HA)
- repmgr
- barman

The main database will run on the repmgr servers. It has primary and standby. If primary down, standby can up. But will take some seconds. At that time, user can't access the database by pending? Isn't there has a good way to make realtime response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With all high-availability solutions you will always have some down-time during a failover, typically less than a minute.

The reason is that the clusterware has to determine reliably that a member is down before it can fail over. That means that failover is only initiated after several attempt to communicate with the cluster member have failed.

You can reduce failover time by making these tests try less often, but that increases the risk of an unnecessary failover (for example, caused by a one-time network glitch). Unnecessary failovers reduce the total uptime of your database, so you don't win anything that way.

Comment: Very professional and clear answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try PgpoolII or PGpool with Regmgr
1. Opensource
2. High Available
3. Pool connection with single external db access port

To reach reasonable high availabe, I think you need has at least 3 servers.

Here is the pgpoolII online document of how to create robust cluster system and avoid the single point of failure or split brain
[image: Cluster System Configuration]

*[Diagram source](https://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/en/html/example-cluster.html)*

Comment: I think you should indicate the source of that diagram, unless you created it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for remind. The source of the diagram is is same as the PgpoolII website manul page: https://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/en/html/example-cluster.html